# How to create a font for free using web tools?

Tags: software-recommendation, font-design

I realize this is an unfortunately vague question. I happen to be working with a designer with really awesome lettering skills, and we were hoping to create a couple fonts in .otf  files. We are at a bit of a loss at how to go about doing this nicely.

The fonts created using http://www.myscriptfont.com really aren't rendering nicely in print, and we were wondering if there is a better way to do this.

(If possible, we would like to use free software - we're already paying a lot for printing and other fees.)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a web tool, I don't believe such a thing exists. There are some free software options, though.

There is [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/), but the last time I tried using it was beyond frustrating. I could not get it to run for very long without crashing (and tried across many different operating systems).  It's even addressed in the FAQ:

> **[Why is FontForge so unstable?](http://fontforge.org/faq.html#Unstable)**
>   *I don't bother much with doing QA. This is a problem. I don't enjoy doing it, and no one is paying me to do it, so little gets done.*

Another is called [BirdFont](http://birdfont.org/), but I have not yet tried it so I can't give you a personal seal of approval.

There is a lot of careful designing that needs to go into font creation, so I think you'll be hard pressed to find an automated solution that will produce a nice looking font. The tool you linked and any like it are like the "CafePress" of font creation: don't expect polished results.

If you're already comfortable designing things in vector, then you've got a good head start for designing a font, but there are many other behind-the-scenes metrics that you'll need to get comfortable with (see diagram below)

[image: Typography Line Terms]
<sup>[Source: Max Naylor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Typography_Line_Terms.svg)</sup>

Comment: +1 for FontForge...I've been working with it and while it's a bit fickle, it's definitely workable. @gersande if you do give it a try and have questions, post them up on this site!

Answer (score -1):

A great and designer friendly online font creator is [Fontark.net](http://www.fontark.net)